# Can I get notification or any observer when application installed or removed from iOS device using MDM?

Tags: python, objective-c, swift, iphone, mdm

I want notification or any observer either **new application installed** or **removed** from iOS device using **MDM profile**

Can I get it?

Thanks

Comment: You will need periodically fetch installed applications on iOS device with MDM and generate notification if something have changed.

Comment: Thanks,
I will fetch installed applications but do you have any idea which notification will generate if something have changed?

Comment: There are no notifications. That's what he's trying to say. You'll have to poll the list of apps from time to time and compare which are missing since the last polling.